# How can I skip numbering the title page?

Tags: templates, thesis

I am currently trying to use this template [University of California thesis template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/52fb8cb233621a613683ecb3) but I am facing a problem with the numbering of the pages, it starts with the page containing the title.

---

I am looking for a way to make the numbering skip the first page.

---

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Do you just want to "no show the page number", or do you want to "not show the page number" + "start from 1 elsewhere" as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\titlepage}
  {\thispagestyle{prelim}}
  {\thispagestyle{empty}}
  {}
  {}
```

To suppress numbering and make the title page not be taken into account for numbering of subsequent pages:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\titlepage}
  {\thispagestyle{prelim}}
  {\thispagestyle{empty}\setcounter{page}{0}}
  {}
  {}
```

The class `ucdavisthesis` uses the `prelim` page style in the title page; this style places the page number centered in the footer and has empty header; changing to the `empty` page style removes the numbering.

Comment: After checking the result it seems that the numbering of the title page was deleted but it is still taken in consideration, the next page number was ii instead of i. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @user3351262 please see my updated answer.